# plot the numerical value of the average on a BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: probability-or-statistics, plotting

Im using `BoxWhiskerChart` to get a boxplot of a matrix of two columns.
I need to read the value of the sample average directly from the plot and not from the axes.
That is I need to plot the number beside the box.
I would also like to add grid lines

```
Needs["StatisticalPlots`"]
BoxWhiskerChart[Transpose[fhat], "Mean"]
```

fhat is an array of dimension 1000 by 4

Comment: please provide the code and data you are useing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some random data

```
fhat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 4}];
```

One can get a `BoxWhiskerChart` with the value of the mean placed below each box and grid lines with

```
BoxWhiskerChart[Transpose[fhat], "Mean", BarOrigin -> Left, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Mean[#], Below] &), GridLines -> Automatic]
```

> [image: BWChart1]

Or with specified vertical grid lines, no horizontal grid lines, and centering of the mean value below the marker

```
BoxWhiskerChart[Transpose[fhat], "Mean", BarOrigin -> Left, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Mean[#], {Mean[#] + 0.5, -0.3}] &), 
 GridLines -> {Range[-1, 1, 0.2], None}]
```

> [image: BWChart2]

Answer (score 0):

### Labeled

You can also wrap each data set with `Labeled`. Using Karsten's example data:

```
fhat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 4}];

BoxWhiskerChart[Labeled[#, Mean[#], Below] & /@ Transpose[fhat], "Mean", 
 BarOrigin -> Left, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

### ChartLabels

```
BoxWhiskerChart[Transpose[fhat], "Mean", BarOrigin -> Left, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, ChartLabels -> Placed[Mean@fhat, Below]]
```

[image]